# nginx not running ssi commands in .shtml file

Tags: nginx, server-side-includes

I can't figure out why SSI is refusing to run. I'm on **nginx 1.25.2**, on **Ubuntu 22.04**

```
server {

    listen      x.x.x.x:443 ssl;
    listen      [::]:443 SSL;
    # other lines 

    include /home/bhccwga/conf/web/bhccwga.org/nginx.hsts.conf*;

    ssi on;

     # rest of code
}
```

I have tried it with very basic code (printing out the time), but this is the same code that was working fine on our old nginx server:

```
<!--#exec cgi="/cgi-bin/ri/ri.cgi"--></div>
```

Is there anywhere else I can check? The code just prints out in the HTML source when viewed in the browser (so its not an execution error, its just not being run)

the config comes up valid:

```
 nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#commands
Nginx never supported `exec` command.

Comment: @AlexeyTen OMG I feel dumb! We have it with Apache and nginx. Technically nginx is in front of Apache, and then we pass stuff through to Apache. I just assumed nginx was handling the shtml stuff. But it seems I was wrong! The reason the SSI wasn't working, was because the apachemodule wasn't enabled:  `a2enmod include`